# php html page - take the URL, do a search replace on it, then output the result into the html

Tags: php, html, replace

**Hi I need a simple way with inline PHP to search/replace the URL string, then output the result into the HTML**

Our checkout cart redirects people to our post-purchase page, and something like the following ends up in the URL bar:

```
http://example.com/postpurchasepage.php?amount=$9.99&firstname=Billy&lastname=Bob
```

More often, based on the browser, they end up with this in their URL bar:

```
http://example.com?amount=%249.99&firstname=Billy&lastname=Bob
```

(converts the `$` into `%24` )

Yes, the cart sends the $ symbol along inside the parameter value.  No I don't want it, nor the %24.  So, the challenge is to remove both the `$` symbol or the `%24` (whichever happens),

Right now I am trying to pull the amount value into the page using `<?php echo @$_GET['amount']; ?>`

For example:

```
<p>Hey <?php echo @$_GET['firstname']; ?> !</p>
<p>Thanks for donating <?php echo @$_GET['amount']; ?></p>
```

However that outputs:

```
<p>Hey Billy !</p>
<p>Thanks for donating %249.99</p>
```

I want it to output:

```
<p>Hey Billy !</p>
<p>Thanks for donating 9.99</p>
```

(or whatever the **amount** value is that was passed from the cart, without the $ symbol or the %24)

**Like I said, basically I am looking for a way to search the URL bar for whatever I define (multiple 'or' type searching), replace with whatever I define, and output the result into the html**

*Any help appreciated!*

Comment: Just don't send the dollar sign in the first place.

Comment: 3rd party cart company is sending it, I can't modify how they send it. Gotta deal with the card I'm being delt

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `urldecode()`

```
echo urldecode("%24"); // $
```

Then you can strip off the leading `$` (if any):

```
$string = (strpos($string)===0) ? substr($string, 1) : $string;
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (or more - depending on your creativity & scenario) to get this done;

1. If you have access to the value of amount before the redirecting occurs, you can strip off the "$" sign and just send in the numeric value and use it there.
2. Otherwise, you can get the value on the page, and then as [willoller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33822/willoller) mentioned, urldecode it and you can then strip the any leading character that is not numeric. (Not sure if performance would be an issue but that's what worked for me several times before)

Here's a sample for your code:

```
    <p>Hey <?php echo @$_GET['firstname']; ?> !</p>
<p>Thanks for donating <?php echo @$_GET['amount']; ?></p>

<?php
$Get_Amount = urldecode($_GET['amount']);

// WHILE LOOP = TO VALIDATE IF VALUE IS NUMERIC
while (is_numeric($Get_Amount)==false) { 
    if (is_numeric(substr($Get_Amount, 0,1))){
        // DO NOTHING = First Character Numeric
        // Might be an issue if you have characters in between the number
        // THIS WILL CAUSE RE-LOOP PROBLEM (Dependent on your scenario)
    }else{
        // TRIM OFF THE FIRST CHARACTER
        $Get_Amount = substr($Get_Amount, 1);
    }
}
?>

<p>Thanks for donating <?php echo $Get_Amount; ?></p>
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

OR -----------------------

You can use the preg_replace function like this:

```
 <p>Hey <?php echo @$_GET['firstname']; ?> !</p>
<p>Thanks for donating <?php echo @$_GET['amount']; ?></p>

<?php
$String_Get_Amount = urldecode($_GET['amount']);

// Here you can add the characters that you wanna delete
// You should not delete anything that is not numeric cause then it would even replace the decimal point
$String_Search_For_Pattern = '/[$]/';

// Replace it with nothing
$String_To_Replace = '';

$String_Get_Amount = preg_replace($String_Search_For_Pattern, $String_To_Replace, $String_Get_Amount);
?>

<p>Thanks for donating <?php echo $String_Get_Amount; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks 93Ramadan Ill try this, but do I have to do all this stripping and validating of character type? Isn't there something simpler that works like a typical  search for "this" or "this" then replace with "that" ?

Comment: @JesseB I thought you might ask that actually! There is a nicer and much simpler and cooler way to do exactly what your saying, search for specific things in a string and replace -- the [preg_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which you can basically provide a character to replace and it will do it .. I'll give you an example in my next comment ;)

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. I am not looking to search/replace certain characters, I am looking to delete ANY EXACT sequence of characters which I put between the single quote marks. Would it work to do $String_Search_For_Pattern = 'anydamnthing.I-want%24hereWhetherNumeric!or!alphabetic&specialcharactersToo'; ?

Comment: Not really, it works using regular expressions so whatever you put as the search string has to be built using the expressions that define the things you are looking for and etc. Have a look at online regular expression builders to get an idea and help build your own search string as well; examples like [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and [Functions Online](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html)